# Better way to find children in XML file than this?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

So I have some varying XML files, they don't all have the same format or data elements. I want to write some code that will get me a list of all the different types of nodes, by checking each node and seeing if it has children or not, then checking the children's children, and so on.

I can write this out so it does it in a static way, but I would rather have it test to see if each node has a node within it or not, and keep drilling down.

For example I have done this:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.iterparse('vx19.xml')
for _, el in tree:
    if '}' in el.tag:
        el.tag = el.tag.split('}', 1)[1]  # strip all namespaces
    for at in el.attrib.keys(): # strip namespaces of attributes too
        if '}' in at:
            newat = at.split('}', 1)[1]
            el.attrib[newat] = el.attrib[at]
            del el.attrib[at]

root = tree.root

for a in root:
    print(a.tag)
    if a[0]:
        for b in a:
            print('\t',b.tag)
            for c in b:
                print('C')
                print('\t\t',c.tag)
                for d in c:
                    print('D')
                    print('\t\t\t',d.tag)
                    for e in d:
                        print('E')
                        print('\t\t\t\t',e.tag)
```

That gives me what I am looking for, but there has to be a better way to write this.

```
B
         Method Def
C
                 TriggerOn
C
                 Formal Expression
C
                 Form Ref
C
                 Actions
D
                         Identifiers
E
                                 Identifier
E
                                 Identifier
E
                                 Identifier
```

I was hoping to write something like, "In this node, check if there are sub-nodes. If not, end. If so, then list out the sub-nodes, AND for each sub-node, are there further sub-nodes? If so....repeat on down until there are no new layers to drill down into."

Thank you!!

Comment: Look up how to implement Breadth-First Search and Depth-First Search. Too large of an answer to post on StackOverflow.

Comment: If your input has a known limit on the number of nestings and that number is lesser than the max recursion limit of the cpython interpreter, you can implement the behaviour by using simple recursion, otherwise you can use a queue and an iterative algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input has a known limit on the number of nestings and that number is lesser than the `max recursion limit` of the `cpython` interpreter, you can implement that behaviour by using simple recursion, otherwise you'll use a list and an iterative algorithm.

**Iterative**:

```
def iterative(root, result: set):
   queue = [root]
   for item in queue:
      result.add(item.tag)
      for elem in item:
         queue.append(elem)
   return result
```

**Recursive**:

```
def recursive(root, result: set):
   for item in root:
      result.add(item.tag)
      for elem in item:
         recurse(item, result)
   return result
```